# How can I add flexible name to event_name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, events

I want to add more flexible name to event_name when I create an event in mysql.

```
 mysql> CREATE EVENT test
 ->     ON SCHEDULE AT '2006-02-10 23:59:00'
 ->     DO INSERT INTO test.totals VALUES (NOW());
 Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I also want to add name like this.

```
 mysql> CREATE EVENT 2sjoira42092ajdfj
 ->     ON SCHEDULE AT '2006-02-10 23:59:00'
 ->     DO INSERT INTO test.totals VALUES (NOW());
```

I got error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Can the event name start with a digit? Probably.. but it looks weird.

Comment: @ethrbunny : Yes, event names can start with digits, and can even solely be digits if they are quoted.  The only reason I know this is because I had the same thought as you did and rushed to check the manual, lol!

Comment: @kinakomochi: If your first event worked, then your second should too, as the name you are using is legal. You are allowed to start with a digit and have up to 64 characters.  Still, try quoting the name and even shortening it and seeing what happens.